# Converting lambda functions to regular functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to convert the following code involving several lambda functions into separate "regular" functions. How would I do this?

I'm working on Pyspark right now. Data source is an RDD

```
result = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0]=='9439').map(lambda x: (x[0], json.loads(x[1])['exposures'])).flatMapValues(lambda x: x).map(lambda x: {'serial_no' : x[0], **x[1]})
```

My attempt:

```
def acct_tuple(x):
    return (x[0], json.loads(x[1])['exposures'])


def flat_map(x):
    return x

def get_tuple(x):
    return {'serial_no': x[0], **x[1]}


rdd = rdd.map(acct_tuple(x)).flatMapValues(flat_map(x)).map(get_tuple(x))
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: But what's the problem with keeping them as lambdas?

Comment: I'm converting this to a script.. I was specifically asked to change lambdas to regular functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the function itself as a parameter, and do not call it, hence:

```
def acct_tuple(x):
    return (x[0], json.loads(x[1])['exposures'])


def flat_map(x):
    return x

def get_tuple(x):
    return {'serial_no': x[0], **x[1]}


rdd = rdd.map(acct_tuple).flatMapValues(flat_map).map(get_tuple)
```